# Magento 2: How to update order status programmatically in custom module?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, magento-2.1.3

```
$orderId = 1;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId); 
$order->setState("processing")->setStatus("processing");
$order->save();
```

Please tell me how I update the order status in Magento 2?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do it like following way

declare below namespace

```
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

$orderId = 1;
//Use constructor injection for Order class. Below $objectManager is just for testing/explanation purpose
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
$orderState = Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
$order->setState($orderState)->setStatus($orderState);
$order->save();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for reply @Dhaval Drcsystems i want update order status only

Comment: You can refer this model so you will get better idea Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment
Check here how they are processing order with code.

Comment: the above code shows  \Magento\Sales\Model\Order not found error

Comment: Can you please show me your file ?

Comment: How to update custom order status? If i have status called 'sent_to_print'?

Comment: @DhavalSolanki - If I want to set the order status as "Pending/New" programmatically then what should I do? Once payment is done, the order status showing as "Processing" but I wanted to show as "Pending/New" similar to "Cash On Delivery". Please advise.

Comment: @Vinayagam It depends on which payment method you are using 
can you please tell me which payment method you are using ?

Comment: Really shouldn't be using the object manager.

Comment: @Dom
Its just example how to achieve function, I know using object manager is not a good way but you can use dependency injection your code Aboe ansser is just demonstration of code .

Answer (score 16):

**Order state update**

To update the order state and and status pro-grammatically in order define the status and state in this format. Initiate order object in the construct function and use that order object in the custom function to update it. To update order state programmatically in model, get order object from the construct function.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
){
    $this->order = $order;
}
public function updateorder(){
    $order = $this->order;
    $order->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
    $order->setStatus(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
    $order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(), 'Order processed successfully with reference');
    $order->save();
}
```

**New order email**

```
$orderid = '10000000';
$order = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($orderid);
$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender')->send($order);
```

Comment: great thanks for reply @calypso  but i want to update only order status

Comment: @Rahulocodewire It is also in comment.

Comment: @ calypso please explain where i put this code in my module

Comment: how i show pending status in controller ?

Comment: @gelanivishal working perfectly thank you

Answer (score 12):

Since **load()** and **save()** are deprecated now (because :)

```
* @deprecated 100.1.0 because entities must not be responsible for their own loading.
* Service contracts should persist entities. Use resource model "load" or collections to implement
* service contract model loading operations.
```

I used the **OrderRepositoryInterface** to load and save the order :

```
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;

public function __construct(
    OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    ...
) {
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
}

...
$order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
$order->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW);
$order->setStatus(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW);

try {
    $this->orderRepository->save($order);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->logger->error($e);
    $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, $e->getMessage());
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: how to update custom order status?

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to @medmek and @prince-patel answer. As question from @jafar-pinjar regarding custom order status, setState and setStatus calls can take on Status Code. For example, custom status code "paid" is created. To update the status/state to an order:

```
...
use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;

class nameOfTheClass {
    ...
    protected $_orderRepository;
    ...
    public function __construct(..., OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository, ...){

        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        ...
    }
    ...
    public function setOrderStatus($orderID, $statusCode){
        try{
            // obtain the order with the order ID
            $order = $this->_orderRepository->get($orderID);
            $order->setState($statusCode)->setStatus($statusCode);
            $this->_orderRepository->save($order);
            return true;
        } catch (\Exception $e){
            // add some logging here
            return false;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

To update the order status:

```
$orderID = 1234; // this is the order ID
$code = 'paid';
$this->setOrderStatus($orderID, $code);
```

Hope that helps someone out there.

Comment: incremental id is like #3000001469-1, not 1234. 1234 is rather order id

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Greck. Updated the response.

Answer (score 4):

Magento 2.2.2 This only works the following way!

```
    $order = $this->order->loadByIncrementId('000000001');
    //$order = $this->order;
    $order->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true)->save();
    $order->setStatus(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true)->save();
    $order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(), 'Order processed successfully with reference again and again');
    //$order->save();
```

But the only problem that I have is that it doesn't updates fully status :
[image]

It only updates the in the grid and the follow:
[image]

Also not possible to create new invoice,shipping and credit memo.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for updating order status via GraphQL then this change in resolver would help.

use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface;

use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;

```
public function __construct(

    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderStatusHistoryRepositoryInterface $orderStatusRepository
) {
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->orderManagement = $orderManagement;
    $this->orderStatusRepository = $orderStatusRepository;
}

       
            $this->orderManagement->cancel($orderData['orderid']);
            $order->setData('state', "cancel");
            $order->setStatus("cancel”);
```