# Magento 2 set order status to processing when paid off by coupon

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, sales-order, order-status

I did notice a setting where you can change order status when subtotal is zero:

**A)** Stores / Configuration / Sales / Payment Methods / Other Payment Methods / Zero Subtotal Checkout

I have also tried the solution mentioned here:

**B)** [Magento 2: How to update order status programmatically in custom module?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164600/magento-2-how-to-update-order-status-programmatically-in-custom-module)

and both fails, any ideas?

Comment: What is your goal? `Zero Subtotal Checkout` is payment methd

Comment: I just want the order status to be processing instead of pending, when customer pays off by coupon

Comment: order status depends on payment method on which payment method you are using?

Comment: I have a coupon that makes order total 0.00 and payment methods disappears after applying it, not sure what method it would be called.

Comment: Yes, if your total is 0 then all your payment method will be hidden (there is no meaning to display payment method if your total is 0) only `Zero Subtotal Checkout` payment method will be display.

Comment: So my plan A is still failing, changed new order status to processing + a cache clean also, but still when i place a test order with zero total and its still showing pending

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72064/discussion-between-mac-a-and-keyur-shah).