# Custom order status between Processing and complete in Magento2

Tags: magento2, orders, order-status, status

I have create custom order status by following below link.

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/sales/order-status-custom.html

I created custom status called "Sent to Printing".

I need this to apply in between **processing** and **complete**. How this can be done?

As per the link i created the status and assigned it to "**Processing**" state. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you confuse "state" with "status" here.

"Processing" and "Complete" are *states*, which means that they have some functionalities associated - for example, an order that is "Complete" can not be cancelled. A *status* is actually just a label for a state, so you choose a *status* if you want to display something special to your sales manager or customer.

The *state* "Processing" also has a *status* "Processing" that is this state's default status, which means that every time an order is in the *state* "Processing", it will also automatically have the *status* "Processing".

When you want to display something else (= you want to display another *status* for an order in the same *state*), you can open this order in the backend; then scroll down to the field where you can enter comments. Above that field, you should see a dropdown menu. This menu allows to set another status. A state can only be changed by using the buttons on the top ("Create shipment", "Create invoice" and so on).

**Update**

To update order state & status programmatically, see here: [Magento 2: How to update order status programmatically in custom module?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164600/magento-2-how-to-update-order-status-programmatically-in-custom-module)

Comment: Still i am not cleared, I need to display processing status also as well as my custom status also, how that can be done?

Comment: I described how to change the status in my answer. You can only display 1 status at once, not 2 at the same time.

Comment: can we update the order status by code programmatically? for custom statuses?

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: Yes that will set to processing state, how can we update to custom status? for example i am reading value from csv file with orderId and status column, how to update the status read from csv?

Comment: That's out of the scope of above question, so please ask a new one. Also, I am pretty sure that this questions has been asked & answered numerous times, so you should Google first and then ask a more specific question if you get any errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81697/discussion-between-jafar-and-simonthesorcerer).