# Magento 2: How to remove the Order Status in admin panel?

Tags: magento2, order-status

In Magento 2 admin panel, I can see there is an option to unassign the status. But, is there any option to **Removes the Default Order Status** in the admin panel? If not, suggest the way how I can remove it.

Please guide.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please update the post wiht a print screen of the column you wish to have removed?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to delete status by admin natively in Magento.
But we can delete the records from the database.
There are two tables:

```
sales_order_status
sales_order_status_label
```

You can find entries like this:

```
SELECT * FROM sales_order_status WHERE status = 'STATUS_CODE';
SELECT * FROM sales_order_status_label WHERE status = 'STATUS_CODE';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage order status under `Store > Settings > Order Status` you can add new status or unassigns order status.

[For more details to add custom order status check this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/272943/how-to-add-one-more-state-after-order-status-and-state-processing)