# Magento 2.3 Change Order Status Programmatically

Tags: orders, order-status, magento2.3

How to Order status change Processing to complete in magento 2.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can Change **status** this way..

```
    $orderId = 1; // here order id

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
                               ->load($orderId); 

    $order->setState("complete")->setStatus("complete");

    $order->save();
```

Comment: can u please help me solve this [issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262077/how-to-add-a-date-picker-recursively-in-magento2-admin-form) @rakesh

Answer (score 6):

You can Change the order status to complete  using repository Class of order entity `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface`

```
    $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderiId);
    $order->setStatus($completeStatus)->setState($completeStatus);
    $this->orderRepository->save($order);
```

**Code Looks Like:**

```
<?php
namespace {ClassNameSpace};

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class Test {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $orderRepository;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository      
    ) {

        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    }
    public function ChangeOrderStatusToComplete()
    {
        $completeStatus = \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_COMPLETE;
        $id = 2;
        try{
            $order = $this->orderRepository->get($id);
            $order->setStatus($completeStatus)->setState($completeStatus);
            $this->orderRepository->save($order);           
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $ex) {
            // error Happen
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Sir If I want to change it **Hold** to **Processing** how can we set it on Processing or any other status??? like in your code it is only for **Complete**.

Comment: @Amit How does this work?
i have a user and the order id = 2 how does this update it? how do i run it

Comment: Once payment is done, the order status showing as "Processing" by default but I wanted to show as "Pending/New" similar to "Cash On Delivery".  If I want to set the order status as "Pending/New" programmatically once the order is placed. What should I do? Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

This is duplicated from this [Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164600/magento-2-how-to-update-order-status-programmatically-in-custom-module?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

$orderId = 1;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order') ->load($orderId);
$orderState = Order::STATE_COMPLETE;
$order->setState($orderState)->setStatus(Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
$order->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

kindly change object manager to di

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $orderRepository = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface');
            $order = $orderRepository->get($orderId);
            $order->setState('awaiting_stock');
            $order->setStatus('awaiting_stock');
            $orderRepository->save($order);
```