# How to add a date picker recursively in magento2 admin form

Tags: magento2, datepicker

How to add a date picker recursively in backend ?

System.xml

```
 <field id="mapping" translate="label comment tooltip" sortOrder="80" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Date off</label>
                    <frontend_model>Companyname\DeliveryDate\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Datemap</frontend_model>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
                    <comment>                        <![CDATA[Allows admins to choose any date off that they want]]>
                    </comment>
                </field>
```

My code:

```
<?php
namespace Companyname\DeliveryDate\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field;

class Datemap extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory
     */
    protected $_elementFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $elementFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $elementFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_elementFactory  = $elementFactory;
        parent::__construct($context,$data);
    }
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->addColumn('field1', ['label' => __('Date'), 'class' => 'input-text required-entry field']);
        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add');
        parent::_construct();
    }

}
?>
<script>
 require([ "jquery", "mage/calendar" ], 
function($){
 $(".field").calendar({ 
 changeYear:true, 
changeMonth:true, 
yearRange: "1970:2050", 
buttonText:"Select Date", 
dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy"
}); 
});
 </script>
```

My output is:

[image]

Comment: Please follow below link https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/dynamic-fields-in-system-configuration/

Comment: Can u please help me to solve the above edit issue @RamkishanSuthar

Comment: Have you done this

Comment: no, it was apply to first one alone@G Prathap

Comment: Tried these https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82264/magento-2-adding-calendar-to-custom-frontend-form

Comment: calendar is appear there is no problem but it was apply to  only one field  i want to apply it for added fields also

Comment: you've added through js right? so check the console if nothing found paste the template file here .
thanks

Comment: yes here a console screen shot https://prnt.sc/mmm11z @G Prathap

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89873/discussion-between-g-prathap-and-divya-sekar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
    require([ "jquery", "mage/calendar" ], 
        function($){
            $('body').on('focus',".field", function(){

            $(".field").calendar({ 
                changeYear:true, 
                changeMonth:true, 
                yearRange: "1970:2050", 
                buttonText:"Select Date", 
                dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy"
                }); 
            });
        });
</script>
```

OR

http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vdFaH/1/

Comment: Hi Divya you can choose any one method

Comment: its working fine but i need it to appear without focus  is there any chance @Birjitsinh

Comment: have you try secound optiojn?$('#addnew').click(function() {//add code here});

Comment: i will tried and update u