# How I can Change Order status like: Order accepted, order out for delivery, Order delivered? frontend(seller)

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-status

I can Change a form submit in frontend .For Example ->

```
<form method="post" action="#">
<select>
    <option value="pending">Pending</option>
    <option value="processing">Processing</option>
    <option value="orderaccepted">Order accepted</option>
    <option value="outfordelivery">order out for delivery</option>
    <option value="orderdelivered">Order delivered</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="submit-orderstatus" class="submit-orderstatus" >
</form>
```

Comment: First, You have to create a custom order state & status. Please check link https://magecomp.com/blog/create-custom-order-status-state-programmatically-magento-2/ Second, you have to update order state & status. Please check link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164600/magento-2-how-to-update-order-status-programmatically-in-custom-module

Comment: please code here

Comment: Can you confirm the below points? You have created a new custom order state & status? Do you want to set or update the custom order state & status only?

Comment: I didn't do anything. please all code